# Android Vector Drawables in Selector for CheckBox (Sdk < 21)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-support-library, vector-graphics

So, i've been adding vector resources to my project. And... they work fine on pre-Lollipop (sdk < 21) devices. I didn't add `gradle:vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary=true` flag to build.gradle. Didn't add `AppComaptDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` to java. Didn't use compat widget in layout. The related xml looks like this:

```
<CheckBox
      ...
      android:background="@drawable/round_checkbox"
      android:button="@null"/>
```

round_checkbox.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/round_check_green"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_check_gray"/>
</selector>
```

Relevant project info:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 24
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
gradle Version 3.3
dependancies:
... [way too many, we are multidexing here]. General:
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
```

Though, been pretty much happy, with my app working fine, I'm confused with why it doesn't crash.
This is a big project, so testing on user is not an option. Any thoughts/suggestions/info will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but there is a version of Android Studio that convert vector to png. Maybe you can analyze the final APK after build whether or not it generate PNG instead of Vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some empiric testing, I can confirm [vsatkh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346785/vsatkh)'s assumption, AS does generate raster graphics (in build/intermediates) from vector drawables, if according gradle flag is absent. So, to use vector drawable one need to follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf), otherwise it'll be simple raster autogeneration.